# Benefits of using QueryDSL vs. Spring Data?

Tags: spring-data, querydsl

Im thinking about using QueryDSL in my project where I am already using Spring Data. I am programming a microservice inclidung a REST-Interface.
What are the main differences between Spring Data and QueryDSL? What are the big benefits of using QueryDSL instead of Spring Data?

Answer (score 3):

Querydsl and Spring Data go along well. While both deal with the domain of persistence they have very different goals.

Querydsl provides a type-safe query API.

Spring Data provides a consistent API to accessing persistent stores, inspired by the ideas of Domain Driven Design, without getting in the way of the user and how she wants to formulate queries.

Therefore there exists an [extension point to combine Spring Data and Querydsl](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl) and you can always implement non-standard queries using Querydsl if they go beyond, what can be easily formulated using the build in Spring Data repositories.